# How to display 300000 as 300,000 in a QT spinbox and label?

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel, qspinbox

I have a number that is displayed in a `QSpinBox` and `QLabel` like this:

```
3570000
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
3,570,000
```

How must I do it?

Comment: QT may have a built-in solution, but [the standard C++ way would be with std::locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Qt 5.3 this is a feature supported by `QAbstractSpinBox`, from which `QSpinBox`is derived, which defaults to `false`. Just call

QSpinBox::setGroupSeparatorShown(true);`

after you've created the `QSpinBox`.

If you are using a version of Qt prior to Qt 5.3, then subclassing is the only choice.

Comment: @goug Good call. Didn't think of that.

Comment: @Qasim: QLabel doesn't do formatting. You have to format the string yourself and then use QLabel::setText. For the formatting, look at QLocale::toString and QLocale::setNumberOptions.

Comment: The editing was truly unnecessary and is not an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to create your own subclass of `QSpinBox` and override the `valueFromText` and `textFromValue` functions. See [Subclassing `QSpinBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html#subclassing-qspinbox) for more info.